# training custom dataset using yolov8 in google drive

Tags: machine-learning, object-detection, yolov8

google colab isn't detecting the .yaml file even though it's in the right path.

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
!ls '/content/gdrive/My Drive/gradProj'
DATA_DIR = '/content/gdrive/My Drive'
!pip install ultralytics
import os

from ultralytics import YOLO

## Load a model
model = YOLO("yolov8n-cls.pt")  # load a pretained model

# Use the model
results = model.train(data='/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml', epochs=300, resume=True, patience=100, save=True)  # train the model
```

here are the errors

```py
Ultralytics YOLOv8.1.24  Python-3.10.12 torch-2.1.0+cu121 CUDA:0 (Tesla T4, 15102MiB)
engine/trainer: task=classify, mode=train, model=yolov8n-cls.pt, data=/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml, epochs=200, time=None, patience=50, batch=256, imgsz=224, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=0, workers=16, project=Classify-aug-test, name=yolov8n-cls3, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=SGD, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=True, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, freeze=None, multi_scale=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, vid_stride=1, stream_buffer=False, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, embed=None, show=False, save_frames=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, show_boxes=True, line_width=None, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.2, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.0001, warmup_epochs=0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.1, nbs=256, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.4, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, auto_augment=randaugment, erasing=0.4, crop_fraction=1.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, boxes=True, random_erasing=0.4, crop_percentage=1.0, save_dir=Classify-aug-test/yolov8n-cls3

Dataset not found ⚠️, missing path /content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml, attempting download...
Downloading https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases/download/v1.0/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml.zip to '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml.zip'...
⚠️ Download failure, retrying 1/3 https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases/download/v1.0//content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml.zip...
⚠️ Download failure, retrying 2/3 https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases/download/v1.0//content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml.zip...
⚠️ Download failure, retrying 3/3 https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases/download/v1.0//content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml.zip...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ultralytics/utils/downloads.py in safe_download(url, file, dir, unzip, delete, curl, retry, min_bytes, exist_ok, progress)
    327                     r = subprocess.run(["curl", "-#", f"-{s}L", url, "-o", f, "--retry", "3", "-C", "-"]).returncode
--> 328                     assert r == 0, f"Curl return value {r}"
    329                 else:  # urllib download

AssertionError: Curl return value 3

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
7 frames
ConnectionError: ❌  Download failure for https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases/download/v1.0//content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml.zip. Retry limit reached.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/ultralytics/engine/trainer.py in __init__(self, cfg, overrides, _callbacks)
    135                     self.args.data = self.data["yaml_file"]  # for validating 'yolo train data=url.zip' usage
    136         except Exception as e:
--> 137             raise RuntimeError(emojis(f"Dataset '{clean_url(self.args.data)}' error ❌ {e}")) from e
    138 
    139         self.trainset, self.testset = self.get_dataset(self.data)

RuntimeError: Dataset '/content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml' error ❌ ❌  Download failure for https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/releases/download/v1.0//content/gdrive/My Drive/Data/google_colab_config.yaml.zip. Retry limit reached.
```

it is supposed to train the model without any errors, we checked the paths multiple times.

Comment: removed [google-drive-ap] because you are not using the google drive api.